# call @font-face in less css

Tags: css, less

how to call font face in less

I tried following code. But its not working

```
@colr : red;

.font-face(@fontfamily) {

        @font-face {
            font-family: @fontfamily;
            src: url("fonts/@{fontfamily}.eot");
            src: url("fonts/@{fontfamily}.eot?#iefix") format('embedded-opentype'),
                 url("fonts/@{fontfamily}.woff") format('woff'),
                 url("fonts/@{fontfamily}.ttf") format('truetype'),
                 url("fonts/@{fontfamily}.svg#@{fontfamily}") format('svg');
            font-weight: normal;
            font-style: normal;
        }
    }


    .class1{    
        color:@colr;
        margin:10px 20px 30px;
        .font-face(bebas_neuebold);
    }
```

Please help me out

Answer (score 1):

This happened because uou forgot to assign `font-family` to your class.

You need to duplicate `font-family` rule in your mixin in order to obtain a slighly different CSS, because inside `@font-face` rule you declare "*font name*" that will be used through `font-family` rule. Here the key modification in LESS code:

**LESS**:

```
.font-face(@fontfamily) 
{
  font-family:@fontfamily;

  @font-face {
    font-family: @fontfamily;
    src: url("fonts/@{fontfamily}.eot");
    ...
  }
}
```

that allows you to obatin the following compiled CSS (here only `.class1` code):

**CSS**:

```
.class1 {
  color: red;
  margin: 10px 20px 30px;
  font-family: bebas_neuebold;
}
```

In this way, you are explicitly assigning `font-family` to be used to `.class1` elements.

---

**A suggestion for better interoperability**:

I suggest you to add also fallback fonts families to final declaration, to advice old browsers that does not support `@font-face` rule or issues with remote fonts downloading.

A possible solution could be:

```
.font-face(@fontfamily) 
{
  font-family:@fontfamily, verdana, arial, sans-serif;

  @font-face {
    font-family: @fontfamily;
    src: url("fonts/@{fontfamily}.eot");
    ...
  }
}
```

---

To complete answer, here the final complete code that I suggest you:

```
@colr:red;

.font-face(@fontfamily) 
{
  //Indicates that the "font-family" to be used is "@fontfamily"
  font-family:@fontfamily, verdana, arial, sans-serif;

    @font-face 
    {
      //Create a new "font-family" with name "@fontfamily", using "src:" as source files
      font-family: @fontfamily; 

      src: url("fonts/@{fontfamily}.eot");
      src: url("fonts/@{fontfamily}.eot?#iefix") format('embedded-opentype'),
           url("fonts/@{fontfamily}.woff") format('woff'),
           url("fonts/@{fontfamily}.ttf") format('truetype'),
           url("fonts/@{fontfamily}.svg#@{fontfamily}") format('svg');
      font-weight: normal;
      font-style: normal;
    }
}

.class1
{    
  color:@colr;
  margin:10px 20px 30px;

  .font-face(bebas_neuebold);
}
```